# Evitar llegada de registros ya existentes en JTable

Tags: java, java-swing, bucles, jtable

Tengo un método el cual pasa los registros que selecciono de mi JTable1(tablaPorFechas) a otro JTable(TablaDestino), hasta ahi todo bien, el problema surge cuando quiero que no se puedan pasar registros que ya se pasaron previamente, edite el codigode mi metodo pasarDatos para que no permita al usuario pasar datos que ya se pasaron pero esta mal, pero la idea ahí esta, si me podrian ayudar facilitandome como realizarlo correctamente, de antemano muchas gracias

```
 private void botonPasarFilaActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                               

        TableModel model = tablaPorFechas.getModel();
        int indexs[] = tablaPorFechas.getSelectedRows();
        DefaultTableModel model2 = (DefaultTableModel) tablaDestino.getModel();
        Object[] row = new Object[10];
     
        
        boolean exists = false;
        String s;
        String w;
        //recorro tablaDestino que es la tabla a donde se pasan los registros
        for(int j = 0; j < tablaDestino.getRowCount(); j++){
            s = tablaDestino.getValueAt(j, 0).toString();
          
            if(tablaPorFechas.getSelectedRow(j, 0).equals(s)){
                exists = true;
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Este registro ya se paso, seleccione registro valido");
                break;
            }
            if(!exists){
               
                for (int i = 0; i < indexs.length; i++) {
                    row[0] = model.getValueAt(indexs[i], 0);
                    row[1] = model.getValueAt(indexs[i], 1);
                    row[2] = model.getValueAt(indexs[i], 2);
                    row[3] = model.getValueAt(indexs[i], 3);
                    row[4] = model.getValueAt(indexs[i], 4);
                    row[5] = model.getValueAt(indexs[i], 5);
                    row[6] = model.getValueAt(indexs[i], 6);
                    row[7] = model.getValueAt(indexs[i], 7);
                    row[8] = model.getValueAt(indexs[i], 8);
                    row[9] = model.getValueAt(indexs[i], 9);
                    model2.addRow(row);
                }
        }
           
           }
          
    }
```

Comment: Pero ¿cuál es el criterio para determinar que dos objetos son iguales?

Comment: ¿De dónde provienen los datos?

Comment: Provienen de una bdd en sql